# Flex. Как разбить 10 элементов по 5 на каждой строчке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Как с помощью flex разбить 10 элементов на 2 строки по 5 элементов. А в мобильном виде на 2 колонки по 5.
Очень надо . Help

Comment: width:20%; flex-wrap:wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настрой только `@media` запрос для мобильного экрана.

```css
.conteiner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.conteiner div {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .conteiner div {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='conteiner'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```